# SL 5 Out of Browser, Elevated Trust - Display PNG From Any LOCAL Directory

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

My understanding is that when I set SL5 to run OOB and elevated trust that I should have wide open access to any directory/file on the local system.  If an external system places png image files into the user's c:\images folder, how can I load the various png files into a XAML Image element?

This line works:

```
image.UriSource = new Uri(value as string);
```

if I set value to a string like "http://blah.com/image1.png"

But fails if I try to set it to:

```
ImageUrl = new Uri(@"C:\images\image3.png")
```

which gets resolved to something like "file:///C:....." when it hits the

```
image.UriSource = new Uri(value as string);
```

line.

How do I display png files in SL5 from any local path on the system running the OOB elevated app?

Comment: Initially this code "image.UriSource = new Uri(value as string);" threw an exception about "value" (part of IValueConverter imp) as being null, even though the debugger showed me that "value" WAS set to a string "file:///C:etc" and not null.  So I forced the the type conversion with string strongUri = System.Convert.ToString(value); and image.UriSource = new Uri(strongUri); and the null exception went away. Now it runs and the objects that have a databound "ImageUrl" property of "http://blah.com/image.png" display png, but any referring to a local file remain empty and do not display the png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work provided that you have elevated permissions set correctly

```
  var bmp = new BitmapImage();
  var stream = new FileStream(@"c:\dir\folder\image.png", FileMode.Open);
  bmp.SetSource(stream);
  stream.Close();
```

If you need to use a uri, this should work:

```
  var bmp = new BitmapImage();      
  var uri = new Uri("c:/dir/folder/image.png");
  bmp.UriSource = uri;
```

Note that the paths are different. The uri path requires forward slashes to be used.

You can then set the source of your image control to the bmp

```
  image.Source = bmp;
```

If you're getting a 'File Operation not permitted' exception you need to double check that elevated permissions is checked in your out of browser settings

Project -> Properties -> 'Out of browser settings'

Check 'Require elevated trust...'

Comment: In the existing code it is relying heavily on "Uri" format all over the place.  Is there an easy way to convert a Uri object back to a normal string path that FileStream will accept?  It will make it easier for me to test quickly if there is.  In the current code I get an exception when I hit the FileStream because "URI formats are not supported."

Comment: I've made an edit that shows how to use a uri. Seems to work fine for me. See how that goes. Note that it uses forward slashes not back slashes in the uri, otherwise it won't work

Comment: Thank you wdavo.  I think it may have just been the forward slashes.  Looking at code too long and pasted file path right from explorer into the string in the code.  Dumb.  It is working now :)  Thanks again!

Comment: And just because I mentioned it, yes there is a way to get a "normal file path" out of a Uri object... Uri.LocalPath